# Forbidden when trying to register-user on axon server 4.4

Tags: axon

After succesfully installing local `axon-server-se version 4.4` I am not able to register users. I am getting 403 back from axon-server (forbidden). Users command, which should list all users on axon-server, returns empty result.

Register a user:

`java -jar axonserver-cli.jar register-user -S https://AXON_SERVER:8024 -t TOKEN -u admin -p test -r ADMIN`

results in

`Error processing command 'register-user' on 'https://AXON_SERVER:8024/v1/users': HTTP/1.1 403  - {"timestamp":1599137927417,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden","path":"/v1/users"}`

Answer (score 1):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/AxonIQ/axon-server-se/issues/149) for Axon and it is already [fixed](https://github.com/AxonIQ/axon-server-se/pull/151) on 4.4.1 version, which was [released](https://github.com/AxonIQ/axon-server-se/releases/tag/axonserver-se-4.4.1) yesterday!

As of version 4.4.1, you have a new properties for this case: `axoniq.axonserver.accesscontrol.adminToken`. This property should get the token you want to use on CLI as Admin.

If you have to stick to 4.4 though, the workaround is to create the very first admin user with access control disabled and enable it afterwards.

Comment: Looks like the workaround is the solution to the problem. Same error occured with version 4.4.1,

Comment: Ok, sorry for that... added a bit more to the answer regarding the new property for this on 4.4.1